# Returning JSONP From Jersey doesnt appear to work

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, jsonp, jersey-test-framework

I'm using Jersey 2.22.1 and this looks so simple. I already have endpoints that return json just fine and now I want them to return jsonp. It appears that all i have to do is annotate with @JSONP, but when I test I don't see the callback wrapper.

From the docs:

```
@GET
@JSONP
@Produces({"application/json", "application/javascript"})
public JaxbBean getSimpleJSONP() {
    return new JaxbBean("jsonp");
}
```

My code:

```
@GET
@Path("/jsonp")
@JSONP
@Produces({"application/json", "application/javascript"})
public Response getHeathJsonp() {
    return Response.ok().entity(ApplicationStatus.getNew("HEALTHY", "Application is healthy!")).build();
}
```

My jquery call:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: "http://foo.com/api/health/jsonp",
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      type: 'GET',
      data: "",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.log(err.toString());
      }
    });
```

My response:

```
{
  "dateTime": {
    "monthOfYear": 1,
    "dayOfMonth": 17,
    "year": 2016,
    "dayOfWeek": 7,
    "era": 1,
    "dayOfYear": 17,
    "centuryOfEra": 20,
    "yearOfEra": 2016,
    "yearOfCentury": 16,
    "weekOfWeekyear": 2,
    "hourOfDay": 12,
    "minuteOfHour": 39,
    "secondOfMinute": 2,
    "millisOfSecond": 666,
    "millisOfDay": 45542666,
    "weekyear": 2016,
    "secondOfDay": 45542,
    "minuteOfDay": 759,
    "chronology": {
      "zone": {
        "uncachedZone": {
          "cachable": true,
          "fixed": false,
          "id": "America/New_York"
        },
        "fixed": false,
        "id": "America/New_York"
      }
    },
    "zone": {
      "uncachedZone": {
        "cachable": true,
        "fixed": false,
        "id": "America/New_York"
      },
      "fixed": false,
      "id": "America/New_York"
    },
    "millis": 1453052342666,
    "afterNow": false,
    "equalNow": true,
    "beforeNow": false
  },
  "description": "Application is healthy!",
  "status": "HEALTHY"
}
```

My ApplicationStatus bean:
package com.foo.model.application;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;

```
public class ApplicationStatus {

    private String _status;
    private String _description;
    private DateTime _dateTime;

    private ApplicationStatus() {   }

    public static ApplicationStatus getNew(String status, String desc) {
        ApplicationStatus stat = new ApplicationStatus();
        stat.setDateTime(DateTime.now());
        stat.setStatus(status);
        stat.setDescription(desc);
        return stat;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return _status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String _status) {
        this._status = _status;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return _description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String _description) {
        this._description = _description;
    }

    public DateTime getDateTime() {
        return _dateTime;
    }

    public void setDateTime(DateTime _dateTime) {
        this._dateTime = _dateTime;
    }

}
```

Project dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1'

    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-server:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.22.1'

    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-processing:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-multipart:2.22.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-sse:2.22.1'

    compile 'com.yammer.metrics:metrics-graphite:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:18.0'
    compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.9'

    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.16'

    testCompile 'junit:junit-dep:4.10'
    testCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
    testCompile 'org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers:jersey-test-framework-provider-grizzly2:2.22.1'
}
```

The json serialization on this bean works just fine from my regular json endpoint, but the jsonp doesn't seem to work... It's so simple i cant even figure what could be wrong.

Comment: from your post your code ("My code:" ) doesn't seem to have either JSONP or "application/javascript". Am I missing something?

Comment: I pasted in the wrong code snip. Corrected now

Comment: MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON refers to "application/json". You might want to add "application/javascript". JSONP docs (2.5.1) say : The acceptable JavaScript media types for JSONP compatible with this annotation are:

application/x-javascript
application/javascript
application/ecmascript
text/javascript
text/x-javascript
text/ecmascript
text/jscript

Comment: I know, but the media type enum doesn't have JavaScript and after much googling I couldn't find and reference to it...

Comment: Thanks for going back and forth with me so fast. I've tried the text versions. I've updated my code above and have re-tested also

Comment: In your test call set the media type to "application/javascript". As it is now I believe it requests "application/json". You may have to use the overloaded String version of request() for the media type.

Comment: I'm trying to test via postman and passing a header of accept : application/javascript but the response comes back as application/javascript with no callback wrapper. You can test it if you please at http://patrickkee.com/api/health/jsonp

Comment: I'm using import org.glassfish.jersey.server.JSONP; is that right?

Comment: I had the import wrong at first but even now, deployed with the GlassFish import I still get no callback. I'll have to keep pounding at it I guess

Comment: You helped me fix a bunch of mistakes though, just still not working

Comment: Maybe I'll write my own annotation, lol

Comment: I haven't redeployed in the past 45 minutes and i don't see any callback wrapper. How are you testing?

Comment: Firefox - GET http://patrickkee.com/api/health/jsonp, Request Headers: Accept: application/javascript = Response: callback({"dateTime":{"monthOfYear":1, ...

Comment: Wierd. My jquery ajax fails with an error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
AppStore.js:34 Error: jQuery22008610289588104934_1453058409698 was not called

Comment: I got it in chrome by adding Accept : application/javascript, so i think maybe there's a bug in Postman or I don't understand how to use postman... Now i just need to correct my jquery ajax call i think.

Comment: Okie and I got the ajax working too! Thanks for helping me pound through it. My issues were:
importing the wrong @JSONP library, postman bug where the Accept header wasnt being sent